# Wishlist products by customer

Tags: wishlist

**How to get all the customer wishlist items in magento using admin panel.???**

I want to get list of products which is been wishlisted by customers..

Comment: Please provide for which Magento version you want it to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To see one customer wishlist in Magento 2.1 you can go to **Customers** and *Edit* the customer that you want. With customer info on screen **Customer Information > Wish List**. For Magento 1.9 it's pretty similar.

You can't see **all the products** that are wish listed for **all the customers** without and extensión.